# Failed review audit for a post, but it looks alright?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. **You**
>   **didn't pass**.

Here's a screenshot of the result, the original post seems to have deleted.

It says this was an audit, and the post has quality issues, spam etc. But I don't see such thing in this post and it seems like a genuine answer.

From my understanding, we don't have to do any technical evaluation on the answers whether they are correct or not right?

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20836711

I can assume that the user may have edited the post later, but isn't it wrong to include such posts to audit the reviewers?

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you
>   should have reviewed differently, see:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20836711. Come back
>   in 4 days to continue reviewing.

I believe this needs to be addressed as it somewhat discourages the reviewers.

---

Edit: To the person who marked it as a duplicate, **This is a not a duplicate of the given question.** The linked question talks about an instance where the OP was unable to determine between a good link and a spammy link.

In that question, you clearly see a link to an external site, and one could argue whether the link is spam. or not. But in my instance, there is no spammy link or any kind of a spam at all in the post.

And I'm not asking how to determine whether a link is spam or not. My question is clearly mentioned above.

Comment: This is why I don't do reviews any more. I refuse to 'AGREE' with things with which I disagree. But this is reflective of the increasingly authoritarian nature of this site.

Comment: @gnat Why do you think it's duplicate? It asks how to determine whether a link is spam or not. My question is different. Here it doesn't have any visible link or spammy content at all, and it looks totally genuine. But the question you linked has a link to an external site and it's a different scenario.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The user edited to remove the spam links from their two posts before it reached the spam flag threshold.

Rolling back the edits at this point would remove these posts as an audit, but will dispute the spam flags. Unfortunately that's how the system works and I don't see any better option.

I've unlocked, rolled back the posts and re-deleted them, as well as lifted your review ban.

Comment: It makes sense. Hope they will do something to avoid such cases. Thanks for lifting the ban!

Comment: I am now seriously considering detecting and skipping all audits. (It would be a lot worse if you didn't unban OP.)

Comment: The system tries to avoid posts that were edited after being flagged, @T.J.Crowder - but in this case, it kept getting spam flags after the last edit.

Comment: When I complained about the audits on Meta and got little agreement, I simply followed the advice to just stop auditing.

Comment: @Shog9 - Man, reading it back, I must have been in a bad mood when I wrote that comment. The point was valid; the tone was not. Apologies.

Comment: @Joshua you are free to try to detect audits, after all, it implies that you pay attention to the reviews, which is the very goal of them. And it’s not very hard, I usually detect them without even trying.

Comment: Simple fix: don't use edited posts as audits

Comment: @Holger: I'd assume Joshua was talking about using one of the various review audit detector scripts floating around. Or possibly writing their own. I wrote one myself a few years ago (because I needed a quick way to find audits so I could make sure that [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup)'s review enhancements don't break them), and it's literally 10 lines of pretty simple JS / jQuery code. It doesn't detect whether it's a "good" or a "bad" audit, though; that would take a bit more code.

Answer (score -4):

In addition to prior versions being spam, the post in the version you reviewed is not "OK".

The call to `df.filter` which the answer recommends is not new; the question already uses it.

> I knew that `df.filter($"c2".rlike("MSL"))` -- This is for selecting the records but how to exclude the records. ?

Regurgitating information from the question is not useful.

You don't need deep technical knowledge, just a superficial check whether the answer is providing new information or just repeating something the question already says.

The correct review action, seeing only the spam-free version, is downvote, then "I'm Done".  It shouldn't be deleted through the flag review process, but it isn't OK either.

If you noticed that the answer was plagiarism, raise a flag for moderator attention, so they can look at all the account's posts (including deleted ones) and see if it is a pattern requiring a stronger action than just deleting the answer.  And also downvote.

If you can't tell whether the answer is just a rehash of the question, use the "Skip" button.

Comment: The text (and likely also the code) [were plagiarized](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-and-spark/9781785280849/0d79be60-ec4f-4e8d-921c-c60f4081cc6a.xhtml); this is a common technique for spammers: cobble together a post that *looks* like it might be relevant, then tack on whatever link they're promoting. Note that there's no downvote or "I'm done" in Low Quality review - recommending deletion is still the right call for a post like this.

Comment: @Shog9 [recommend deletion on a spam post is *the wrong* call in the queue.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238647/213575) We want users to flag them, not to just delete them. Likewise we want 20kers to flag post as spam, not to vote to delete.

Comment: Recommending deletion of plagiarized nonsense is absolutely the right call, @Braiam. If it happens to also be spam... Well, fortunately you can do both.

Comment: @Shog9 still you are showing non-plagiarized spam post in audits, in which case it is the wrong call all around.

Comment: And if you click "looks OK" that's still the most wrong choice, @Braiam.

Comment: @Shog9 who is suggesting to do that? For me any action that isn't flag as spam is the wrong one. Same with plagiarized post. Without a way to measure it, we can't address it.

Comment: I don't know why this is being downvoted. I agree. There is this weird aversion to comprehending the content of a post, where people say that editors or reviewers should basically only be spell-checking. If that's all people ever did, this site would be significantly less useful.

Comment: You do you, then, @Braiam. The entire discussion here centers around failing an audit - that's triggered by Looks OK.

Comment: @Shog9 No, the entire discussion is centered in failing an audit that no sensible person would *ever be able to pass or fail*, if they did the right thing and worse of all teach the reviewer to do the wrong thing.

Comment: This still sounds like you're arguing for Looks OK, @Braiam. That answer was not, at any point, "OK". You can argue for flagging all you want, but no one here is saying "don't flag". Skip is good. Deletion is good. Flagging is good. Heck, if you understand the question well enough to answer it you could edit that answer into a real answer and that'd *still* be better than clicking "Looks OK". If you prefer one of those to another, that's entirely your prerogative; I don't really care as long as it doesn't stay on the site.

Comment: No @Shog9. [I'm arguing for not using spam as audits.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374043/792066) Any other post would do, just not spam.

Comment: Coulda said that up-front, @Braiam, instead of going off about flagging. I'm open to suggestions for other criteria here...

Comment: @Ben Voigt, thanks for your input. But I don't think any answer which is technically inaccurate should be flagged just for that. Because I have flagged such posts in the past, and this is the response I have received. "declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer ". Since I've got that for the flags I made, I too don't check for technical inaccuracies when I review.

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal: I didn't even cover technical inaccuracy.  And I said if you didn't detect the plagiarism (and the spam was edited out before you saw it), I said you should downvote, not flag.  But don't hit "Looks Ok" on something you downvote.  Downvote+don't flag is also appropriate for technical inaccuracy.

Comment: @Ben Voigt oh, I get it. I agree as well, such posts shouldn't be flagged. But what could be the right option to select there when reviewing such posts?

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal: It depends on the queue (low quality vs close votes vs first posts vs late posts).  If downvote is available in the queue, use that and then "I'm Done".  For low quality posts review where the voting is disabled, click over to the question and vote there, and in the queue choose "Skip".