# Edited post used for audit

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-audits

I was recently temporarily banned from audit following the following bad review:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24433630 in case you cannot fully access the review, here is a screenshot

[image: audit screenshot]

To me, the messages, comments and the fact this message was edited (I was unable to access the edit history) strongly suggests the first version of the answer contained spam and/or offensive language, but this has been edited out.

At the end, the answer I was asked to review looked acceptable to me (e.g. I leave it up to the community to upvote/downvote/accept this answer based on its technical accuracy).

I will patient a few more hours before reviewing (not a big issue), but I wanted to take this opportunity to report what could be a bug in the audit system: the audit system picked an answer, and the test was based on the first version of that answer, instead of the current (and edited) version of this answer.

FWIW, there are similarities with [Failed review audit for a post, but it looks alright?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373986/failed-review-audit-for-a-post-but-it-looks-alright) except I am making a suggestion on how to fall into this again.

Comment: yeah, if the post isn't spam at the time of flagging, it should not have been spam flagged.

Comment: in the meantime I've lifted the review ban (but be careful as the next failed audit in the week will be a duration of four days). You can use my userscript [ReviewQueueHelper](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReviewQueueHelper.user.js) to skip audits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a post wasn't spam at time of flagging, the spam flags should not have been validated otherwise we get incorrect review audits like these.

Similar to the issue you linked ([Failed review audit for a post, but it looks alright?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373986/failed-review-audit-for-a-post-but-it-looks-alright)), I've cleared the spam flags and re-deleted the answer.

Comment: generally speaking, would it be simpler (and quite side-effect free) **not** to use **edited** questions/answers for audit?

Comment: nope, according to staff, this is by-design and is not subject to change. It is more appropriate not to spam flag content that doesn't look spammy, so I will notify the spam flaggers.